# SVG d Keyframe animations Not working IOS

Tags: css-animations

My animation works fine on desktop, but not on mobile.

I am using a JS plugin to animate the line work. The JS works great, but the KEYFRAMES animation does not seem to work on mobile.

I am attempting to animate the SVG d path by adding a new class with a delay on the transition.

Like I stated, works great on desktop. not mobile.

http://envision.overdrivedesign.com/

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

-Marc

```
.st1-ani {
    animation-name: path;
    animation-duration: 3.5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes path {
    0% {
        d: path('M115.9,32.7l-80.5,0l0,79.9l80.5,0L115.9,32.7z');
    }

    75% {
        d: path('M115.9,32.7l-80.5,0l0,79.9l80.5,0L115.9,32.7z');
    }

    100% {
        d: path('M106.6,25.2L27.9,42l16.7,78.2l78.7-16.9L106.6,25.2z');
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes path {
    0% {
        d: path('M115.9,32.7l-80.5,0l0,79.9l80.5,0L115.9,32.7z');
    }

    75% {
        d: path('M115.9,32.7l-80.5,0l0,79.9l80.5,0L115.9,32.7z');
    }

    100% {
        d: path('M106.6,25.2L27.9,42l16.7,78.2l78.7-16.9L106.6,25.2z');
    }
}


@-moz-keyframes path {
    0% {
        d: path('M115.9,32.7l-80.5,0l0,79.9l80.5,0L115.9,32.7z');
    }

    75% {
        d: path('M115.9,32.7l-80.5,0l0,79.9l80.5,0L115.9,32.7z');
    }

    100% {
        d: path('M106.6,25.2L27.9,42l16.7,78.2l78.7-16.9L106.6,25.2z');
    }
}

@-o-keyframes path {
    0% {
        d: path('M115.9,32.7l-80.5,0l0,79.9l80.5,0L115.9,32.7z');
    }

    75% {
        d: path('M115.9,32.7l-80.5,0l0,79.9l80.5,0L115.9,32.7z');
    }

    100% {
        d: path('M106.6,25.2L27.9,42l16.7,78.2l78.7-16.9L106.6,25.2z');
    }
}
```